# If the word is omitted, is the meaning of the word omitted together?

Tags: meaning

If the word is omitted through the grammar, should the meaning of the word be omitted together?

For example, I saw James working out as (he did) before.

You see there disappeared ‘he did’ between ‘as’ and ‘before.’ Then the meaning of ‘he did’ disappeared together?

Comment: Yes, the new sentence is ambiguous because 'as before' might refer to 'I saw'.

Comment: If you omit *working out as he did before*, then you're left with *I saw James*, which definitely removes some meaning from the sentence. But generally, if you're studying English and someone tells you you can omit a certain word in the sentence, it's implied that you can do so without changing the meaning (eg. *If it's possible* -> *If possible*).

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said (and Maciej! :) But I think that if there's nothing at all between ***as*** and ***before***, the only *possible* interpretations are *as **he worked out** before* OR *as **I saw** before*. You can't infer meanings like *as **I worked out** before*, or *as **you saw / worked out** before*.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Hi Michael, if something is omitted, another words get an extra meaning, or just something omitted is inferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a word that is omitted can be deduced.  For example in parallel constructions:

> John went for a walk, but Mary didn't.

In this construction the words "go for a walk" have been omitted.  But their meaning can be deduced.  The sentence means "... but Mary didn't go for a walk."

But in general, omitted words can't be deduced.

> John went for a walk.

Here I have omitted the words "to the shops".  You can't deduce this from the words I said.  So the meaning of "to the shops." is omitted completely.

I hope you can see how the two examples are different.

Comment: Then it has no actual meaning but the meaning is implied?

Comment: I mean the literal meaning.

Comment: In the first case, the meaning "Mary didn't go for a walk" is literal.  It is implied by the syntax.  In the second, the omitted words can't be deduced. The sentence "John went for a walk" does not imply that he went to the shops.

Comment: Can I ask something? If ‘go for a walk’ is omitted, then ‘Mary didn’t’ gets an extra meaning, or just suggests that?

Comment: I mean ‘Mary didn’t’ get a new meaning that Mary didn’t go for a walk or just ‘Mary didn’t’ suggests that Mary didn’t?

Comment: The sentence  "John went for a walk but Mary didn't" means that Mary didn't go for a walk. There is **nothing special about English** similar things happen in your language (I don't know what language you speak, but this is universal)  It is not that the words get a new meaning.  But rather the whole sentence has a meaning. Meaning is **always** understood in context.

Comment: Thank you. I understood finally.

Answer (score 0):

Most often, omitting qualifiers like this leads to *ambiguity*, rather than *changing* the meaning, since the listener doesn't know *what* you omitted.

So:

> I saw James working out as before.

Could be:

> I saw James working out as he worked out before.

Or:

> I saw James working out as I saw him before.

You have to decide if your listener is likely to guess the correct version, or whether you need to be more specific.

I don't think it makes sense to say it "removes the meaning" - the "as before" still tells the listener that it cannot mean:

> I saw James working out for the first time

Obviously if you remove enough, then the sentence has so many possibilities that you are no longer communicating the same thing:

> I saw James

This includes all the previous possibilities, but the listener has no hope of guessing the details you've missed out.